# Efficiently query a XML column in SQL table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, xmltype

We are storing a Untyped XML data into one of our tables. We need to find data based on specific values in certain XML nodes. The XML (simplified) in question is as below.

```xml
<Session id="4f3d4a2c-4f3e-4e53-816c-e0e1b10ee5ad" TimeStamp="2015-09-15T12:02:48">
  <Entries>
    <Entry DataItemId="System.Security.User.IsBroker">
        <Value>True</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry DataItemId="System.Security.User.IsOfficeAdmin">
        <Value>False</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry DataItemId="System.Security.User.BrokerId">
        <Value>32165498</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry DataItemId="System.Security.User.DisplayName">
        <Value>Mike Pearsons</Value>
    </Entry>
    <Entry DataItemId="Address.Line1">
        <Value>Long Marston</Value>
    </Entry>
   <Entry DataItemId="Address.Line2">    
       <Value>End Cottage</Value>
   </Entry>
   <Entry DataItemId="Address.Line3">    
       <Value>End Cottage</Value>
   </Entry>
   <Entry DataItemId="Address.Postcode">    
       <Value>End Cottage</Value>
   </Entry>
    .....
    .....
  </Entries>
</Session>
```

Now we have to search for records where the Address1 is like '*some user entered text.*'

Currently we are using the following query to achieve the same

```
SELECT column1, column2, column 3, XMLColumn
FROM tblXMLData
WHERE 
(XMLColumn.value('(/Session/Entries/Entry[@DataItemId="Address.Line1"]/Value)[1]', 'varchar(210)'))
LIKE ('%sometext%')
```

Though this is giving us the desired results but I was just wondering if there is more efficient way to achieve this or probably a faster way. The query sometime takes couple of minutes to return the results (from 15k records).

Comment: SQL is very slow on XML... i can just suggest to destructurate the XML in a table if you Need to do many query over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, which is about half the cost of the query you posted. The advantage is that it does not have to convert XML data to SQL data, which lowers the overhead:

```
DECLARE @Address varchar(210) = UPPER('user entered text')

SELECT  *
FROM    tblXMLData
WHERE   XMLColumn.exist('/Session/Entries/Entry[@DataItemId="Address.Line1" and contains(upper-case(.), sql:variable("@Address"))]') = 1
```

If you find that you run this type of queries a lot, you can also consider [XML index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Zoff Dino. It does makes it bit quicker. :) I would  also like to add . There were some other conditions we need to check as well. So I filtered all the records with other conditions first, stored the resultset in table variable and then did a search again on filtered records on XML column.